# Establish a savepoint and rollback to it in a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL package that provides a transaction API for creating an instance of an entity (say a new customer).  The API involves several DML steps.

There is a view that exposes instances of this (customer) entity and there is an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view that calls the transaction API whenever someone inserts into the view.

Normally, I would like my transaction API to not know or care about whether it is being called from a trigger.  I want it to work like a typical API (typical around here, anyway):

- Establish savepoint
- Do steps 1-3 of DML
- Do NOT commit (leave that to caller / client)
- On others rollback to savepoint

The problem is that an API like this fails if called from a trigger.

I understand why Oracle cannot allow us to commit or rollback in trigger.  But why does Oracle not allow us to rollback to savepoint that the trigger established?

How can I write my API so that:

1. It cannot have side-effects if any DML step fails halfway through
2. It's successful work is commited when the caller / client commits (i.e., autonomous transaction is a no-go)
3. It does not rely on the caller to `raise_application_error` if it fails.  (Obviously, if I could rely on trigger callers to do this and on client code to then `rollback`, I won't need to worry about side-effects).

Comment: As far as  I can tell, you can't COMMIT nor ROLLBACK in a trigger unless it is an autonomous transaction. Your #2 says that it is a no-go. Therefore, my conclusion would be that you can't do it (but I'll gladly hear other suggestions).

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/oramag/the-trouble-with-triggers.html

Comment: Don't use a view/trigger for this. Instead provide a stored procedure that the user calls.

Comment: @PaulW - Not really a good option for me.  The UI technology we use (APEX) is good at doing CRUD out of the box - inserts, updates, deletes.  Yes, we can make it call PL/SQL instead, but then we're doing more work.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I don't see most of that article applying to `INSTEAD OF` triggers.

Comment: It sounds like your UI choice is severely limiting. The kind of task you have in mind is perfectly suited for a stored procedure.  But to answer your original question, no you cannot control transactions (commit, savepoint, rollback) within a trigger if you do not declare it as an automomous transaction. That's to prevent a trigger from modifying data that would undermine Oracle's commitment to a read-consistent view of data for the originating DML.  You'll have to give up one or more of your design parameters.

Comment: Have you considered object oriented? You could insert a whole set of complex relationships in a single insert call to an object table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your statement. PL/SQL programs automatically have a "natural" savepoint at their commencement, so that if it fails, it will rollback any changes it made, but leave existing changes in the current transaction untouched, eg

```
SQL> create table t ( x int );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure my_api(p_fail boolean) is
  3    v int;
  4  begin
  5    insert into t values (4);
  6
  7    insert into t values (5);
  8
  9    if p_fail then
 10      v := 1/0;
 11    end if;
 12
 13    insert into t values (6);
 14  end;
 15  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (3);

1 row created.

SQL> exec my_api(false);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> select * from t;

         X
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6

6 rows selected.
```

API worked, so pre-API changes PLUS the API changes are all there.  I'll roll back now to an empty state and let the API fail during execution

```
SQL>
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> select * from t;

no rows selected

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (3);

1 row created.

SQL> exec my_api(true);
BEGIN my_api(true); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at "MCDONAC.MY_API", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
SQL> select * from t;

         X
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

My API inserts are rolled back but the pre-API inserts are still there.

Comment: I'll check this out tomorrow.  I believe you may be confusing statement level implicit rollback-on-error with "PL/SQL programs" in general.  My API wouldn't be the top level call, so I think I am still relying on the calling code to either rollback or raise an error.  If the calling code handles the exception from my API, I think my partial results will get committed.  But I'll check it out.